# Need to print a document or a blank page to a HP M452 printer using a bat file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

Hello need to print using a bat file; could be a blank txt file or any way of printing a blank page.

Thanks

Comment: @MarcB, use `> prn echo/`; your command line prints `"" `...

Comment: Ok so where do I enter the printer's IP?

Answer (score 0):

To print anything, we would have to use the `print` command. Type this...

```
print /D:printingDeviceNameGoesHere c:\the\file\I\want\to\print.txt
```

Hope this was helpful, good luck with printing a blank pages(?).